Parallel performance with xarray and dask
I am trying to perform operations in parallel on a very large array using xarray. My current approach is roughly as follows:
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Read dataset (netCDF4). Holds data variable 'p2(time, distance)'
data = xr.open_dataset('some_file.nc', chunks={'time': 'auto'})

# Compute mean of a slice along the time axis
start = np.timedelta64(7,  'h')
end   = np.timedelta64(19, 'h')
mean1 = data.p2.sel(time=slice(start,end)).mean('time')

# Compute mean of another slice
start = np.timedelta64(20, 'h')
end   = np.timedelta64(24, 'h')
mean2 = data.p2.sel(time=slice(start,end)).mean('time')

# Compute some weighted average, obtain the result as numpy array
wavg = ((0.2*mean1 + 0.8*mean2) / 16).compute().data

# Do some work with wavg ...

I was expecting that work on the array would be performed in parallel using all avaliable CPUs, but instead only a few CPUs (about 30 of 256 available CPUs running at about 30% load) are used and memory usage is rather low. As a result the operations are slow and inefficient. I have already tried to change the chunk size and to chunk the array along the distance axis or along both axis. But all these attempts did little impact on the CPU usage. Is my approach wrong or do I miss something here? I am new to xarray and dask, so any help would be appreciated and sorry if I missed something obvious!

There can be many answers to this kind of behaviour. How big is your Dataset? Which dmensions? How many chunks? What is your infrastructure, the speed of your disk, bandwith of your network?

Hi @GuillaumeEB, thank you very much for your comment! The only parameter you named that I can effectively influence is the chunk size. I already experimented with that. All other parameters (Size of Dataset ~200GB, Dimensions: time and distance, HPC infrastructure, bandwidth) are fixed. My main concern was if maybe I did something obivously wrong or ineffective in my code?

What are the dimensions of your dataset? The default chunking? Considering what you are doing, you probably want to have chunks witht he complete time dimension, but maybe your data is not organised like that. Besides, only the chunk you need to read for your operations will trigger tasks.
